# How to inspect a docker image in docker hub?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Is there a way to do `docker inspect` for an image that exists on docker hub and wasn't pulled locally?

I'm a bit confused about the usage of the docker cli when it comes to docker hub. I can `docker login`, but then can't use that login to perform any remote action other than pull or push.

Comment: Not sure it's possible via CLI but on the web UI you can by navigating to the tags e.g. [here for an nginx image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/nginx/library/nginx/mainline-alpine-perl/images/sha256-bb6c654c38fc1a6e6c3375c673296aa33e9b9d95aa987dfd0490d2f4c5dbb2a8?context=explore)

Comment: It seems you can now. This package seems to be able to do it:
https://github.com/containers/skopeo It says it can:
> [Inspect] a remote image showing its properties including its layers, without requiring you to pull the image to the host. I found it on this blog post:
https://ops.tips/blog/inspecting-docker-image-without-pull/ It uses the "Docker Registry HTTP API V2", described here: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/ Archived links in order of appearance: - https://web.archive.org/web/20210907202916/https://github.com/containers/skopeo
- https://web.archive.org/web/20210905214148/ht

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the docker hub documentation -

> Docker itself provides access to Docker Hub services via the docker
>   search, pull, login, and push commands.

It does not look like you can do a docker inspect without pulling one image

Comment: I guess it's pulling and then inspecting then... bummer

Answer (score 4):

There's an API to do this. Docker provided their [registry 2 API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/), and more recently, the OCI [distribution-spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/main/spec.md) was released. This covers how to query the registry for the manifest and blobs. And in the registry, what you are most likely looking for is in the [config](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/config.md) blob, which is json formatted and have almost all the same fields you see in the `docker inspect`.

What's less covered is authentication, and that can get a bit complicated depending on the registry. Docker Hub uses bearer tokens, so an example script that pulls the manifest and then the config with an anonymous bearer token looks like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

ref="${1:-library/ubuntu:latest}"
repo="${ref%:*}"
tag="${ref##*:}"
token=$(curl -s "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:${repo}:pull"
 \
        | jq -r '.token')
digest=$(curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" \
              -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
              -s "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${repo}/manifests/${tag}" \
         | jq -r .config.digest)
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
     -s -L "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${repo}/blobs/${digest}" | jq .
```

There are a variety of tools that do all of these API calls for you. Off the top of my head are:

- RedHat's Skopeo
- go-containerregistry's crane CLI
- regclient's regctl CLI

I'm a bit biased as the author of regclient. The resulting command there looks like:

```
$ regctl image inspect localhost:5000/library/alpine:latest
{
  "created": "2021-08-27T17:19:45.758611523Z",
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "os": "linux",
  "config": {
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "/bin/sh"
    ]
  },
  "rootfs": {
    "type": "layers",
    "diff_ids": [
      "sha256:e2eb06d8af8218cfec8210147357a68b7e13f7c485b991c288c2d01dc228bb68"
    ]
  },
  "history": [
    {
      "created": "2021-08-27T17:19:45.553092363Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:aad4290d27580cc1a094ffaf98c3ca2fc5d699fe695dfb8e6e9fac20f1129450 in / "
    },
    {
      "created": "2021-08-27T17:19:45.758611523Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD [\"/bin/sh\"]",
      "empty_layer": true
    }
  ]
}
```